# Ruby array object find

Tags: ruby, arrays, attributes, find

I am trying out ruby by making a program i need. I have a custom class, and I need an array of objects of that class. This custom class has some attributes that change in the course of the program.
How can I find a specific object in my array, so I can access it and change it?

```
class Mathima
  attr_accessor :id, :tmimata

  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
    @tmimata = []
  end
end


# main
mathimata = []

previd = id = ""
File.read("./leit/sortedinput0.txt").lines do |line|
  array = line.split(' ')          # i am reading a sorted file
  id = array.delete_at(0)          # i get the first two words as the id and tmima
  tmima = array.delete_at(0)

  if previd != id
    mathimata.push(Mathima.new(id))  # if it's a new id, add it
  end

  # here is the part I have to go in mathimata array and add something in the tmimata array in an object. 

  previd = id
end
```

Comment: How do you identify which Mathima object you want to add something to? And what is that "something", is it the contents of tmima?

Comment: thank you all. I used a hash for mathimata and it's working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Hash for mathimata as Greg pointed out:

```
mathimata = {}
File.read("./leit/sortedinput0.txt").lines do |line|
  id, tmima, rest = line.split(' ', 3)
  mathimata[id] ||= Mathima.new(id)
end
```

Comment: As `ids` gets longer this will get slower and slower because of the lookup. A Hash would be faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
mathima = mathimata.find{|mathima| mathima.check() }
# update your object - mathima
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.find()` lets you search sequentially through an array, but that doesn't scale well.

I'd recommend that if you are dealing with a lot of objects or elements, and they're unique, then a Hash will be much better. Hashes allow indexed lookup based on their key.

Because of you are only keeping unique IDs either a Set or a Hash would be a good choice:

```
mathimata.push(Mathima.new(id))  # if it's a new id, add it
```

Set is between Array and a Hash. It only allows unique entries in the collection, so it's like an exclusive Array. It doesn't allow lookups/accesses by a key like a Hash.

Also, you can get your first two words in a more Ruby-like way:

```
array = line.split(' ')          # i am reading a sorted file
id = array.delete_at(0)          # i get the first two words as the id and tmima
tmima = array.delete_at(0)
```

would normally be written:

```
id, tmima = line.split(' ')[0, 2]
```

or:

```
id, tmima = line.split(' ')[0 .. 1]
```